# wordpress site has multiple redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl

I have a wordpress site. I am using the `Simple SSL` plugin to redirect from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`.

In our performance analytics tools we are seeing that there are multiple redirects. Basically its doing this:

```
Problem: from non-www to http://www, then from http://www to https://www
Fix: change this to redirect straight to https://www
```

Here is the `.htaccess` files relevant section.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/wp-admin/ [R,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.5.21]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That's responsible for the non-www redirect, and it sits before the other rules. Change this to redirect to https, and you're done.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, this only accounts for example.com, but not something.example.com. If you have *.example.com set up in your DNS, you might want to change that condition to something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$` to match any host that isn't www.example.com.

Comment: i made that change. I still see `example.com`->`https://example.com`->`https://www.example.com`

Comment: i actually delete the two lines and that got rid of the hop.